# Selenium webdriver functions are not showing in autosuggestion list pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I have installed Python pip selenium pycharm. all works but I see that the autosuggestion box doesn't show the web driver functions. is there a reason for this?

Selenium is installed for project interpreter in pycharm

[This is how autosuggest list looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHkMQ.png)

[And this is how i expect it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywbtC.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing Selenium many folder are installed in the pythonxxx folder. Keep the folder Lib > site-package > Selenium and delete the other Selenium folder in python.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Selenium Module was missing, i have followed these steps and it worked for me thanks
In your PyCharm project:

- Press Ctrl+Alt+s to open the settings on the left column,
- Select    Project Interpreter On the top right there is a list of
  python binaries found on your system, pick the right one
- See if pyselenium  is there in the list
- If not in the list,  click the + button to install additional python
  modules
- Select "pyselenium" and install it

Answer (score 0):

you should know where the 'chromedriver.exe' file is located and pass the path in the code, in my case I download the chrome driver and put in the scripts file in python:

**PATH = "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts"**

**driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)**